# how to choose different json file to loop?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, frontend

I am new to react. I write a script to loop a json file(../a.json) to show cities on screen. Inside a.json, it's a list of city information in UK.

Such as :
["Avon",
 "Bedfordshire"
 ...
 ...
 "Tyrone"
]

The code will loop this a json file and show each city in the screen. 
Now I want to add a param to let people choose which country to show. I add another 4 json file,

import b from "../b.json";

import d from "../d.json";

import e from "../e.json";

import f from "../f.json";

I also created enum type Locale, but I don't know how to adjust code in code file 3. Would you help take a look?

Can I create a Map in code file 3, and based on what locale passed from Home, I can provide json file. Does it work? How should I adjust code?

```
Code file 1
```

```
Code file 3
```

Comment: You can add a dropdown to your `file3` which will have list of locals .. and when user will select any language, then update `this.state.localeDate`

Comment: Thank you very much. I am very new to react. How to add dropdown? And I don't know how to adjust code in code file 3

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like the below code. Add all the locals in an object. Then onChange of select update the localData.

```
import React from "react";
import ES from "../data/ES.json";
import IT from "../data/IT.json";
import UK from "../data/UK.json";

const locals = {
  UK: UK,
  ES: ES,
  IT: IT
};

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      index: 0,
      selectedLocal: "UK",
      localData: locals["UK"]
    };
  }

  onChange = e => {
    this.setState({
      index: 0,
      localData: locals[e.target.value],
      selectedLocal: e.target.value
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <select value={this.state.selectedLocal} onChange={this.onChange}>
          {Object.keys(locals).map(local => {
            return <option value={local}>{local}</option>;
          })}
        </select>
        <div className="hints-on-home-screen">
          <div
            style={{
              fontSize: this.props.testFontSize
            }}
          >
            {this.state.localData[this.state.index]}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. But I want to create export enum Locale {}, how to use this enum type Locale? I want to pass Locale from Home to Test file

Comment: Sorry I don't understand it. Would you explain more?  onChange = e => {} (what's this e means?)

Answer (score 2):

In your `Home` component, create a `select` with all countries as `options`. Maintain a state and update it upon `onChange` and pass it on to your `Test` component.

**Home Component**

```js
import * as React from "react";
import { Locale } from "../component/testLocale";


type Props = {
    testLocale: Locale.UK
}

export class Home extends React.Component<Props, any> {
    state = {
        testLocale: Locale.UK
    }
    handleChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({testLocale: e.target.value})
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="home-background">
                <select onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.testLocale}>
                    {Object.keys(Locale).map(country => <option value={Locale[country]}>{country}</option>)}
                </select>
                <Test testLocale={this.state.testLocale}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. But I want to pass locale from Home to Test. How should I adjust Test file (code file 3)?

Answer (score 0):

what you want to do is add some way to get the chosen json from the user, a [Picker](https://reactnative.dev/docs/picker) (its a dropdown list) is a good choice for this one, feed it the enum lists you have, and make a `state` called `local` or something, you'll use this state to handle the selected local, so you'll have something like this for your `Picker` `onValueChange`

```
onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => setSelectedLocal(itemValue)}
```

Note that react native uses the `hook api` in your case, you do something like:

```
onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => this.setState({locale: itemValue})}
```

and use `local` as a prop for `Test`

```
<Test testLocale={this.props.local}/>
```

Answer (score -1):

See this solution,

Pay careful attention to how everything is configured.

This is a common strategy to manipulate elements using state and data structures.

[Stackblitz Example Solution](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-aurw1h?embed=1&file=index.js)